# How to delete everything before character

Tags: notepad++

How do I do this in notepad ++

From this

```
bird|air|wind|table

pc|laptop|shoes|carpet

word|drink|water|earth
```

to this

```
air|wind|table

laptop|shoes|carpet

drink|water|earth
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. You might try http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a macro.

Position your cursor on the first line before the first character.

From the menu choose 'Macro > Start Recording'

Then type:

Ctrl+F > '|' > Enter > Esc > Right Arrow > Shift + Home > Delete > Down Arrow

Then choose 'Macro > Stop Recording'

Then you can either click Ctrl + Shift + P for each line or Choose 'Macro > Run a Macro Multiple Times > Run until the end of file'

Basically what you're doing is enter a set of steps for Notepadd++ to follow. First you find the first | character, select it and everything before it, delete it and then go down to the next line. After saving this macro, every time you re-run it it will perform those steps again. You just need to make sure your steps are recorded in a way that it will work on every single line in the file.

Hope that helps.